# Is there a plugin for google-repo

Tags: android, repository

For Android the Version Control is done using Git and Repo.
I would like to know if there is an Eclipse Plugin for Repo.

Answer (score 2):

No repo is python oriented no eclipse plugin

Answer (score 0):

E-git is versioning control for eclipse: http://www.eclipse.org/egit/

Comment: I know about e-git, repo is different.